# Is it haram to work on a pornography website out of financial need or desperation?

Tags: fiqh, work

I was looking for web developing projects in freelancer and found a project that said they need a video tool for Adult Site. As Muslim, I can't do it ruin my akhirah. So I decided to send them a proposal while intending to delete their whole server to save someone from getting sinful because of this website. I just want to do it for Allah SWT. Please, can you give me any suggestions or advice of any kind? I have not yet deleted it.

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: My question is that if it's right or wrong in Islamic perspective cuz I'm saving people from watching porn.

Comment: What can i do to repent.

Comment: Oh Allah i deleted it ya rab I deleted. What is the thing I can do to repent. Please brother tell me.

Comment: Change the title and narrative, i.e. “Is it haram to work on a porn site.” That would be a legitimate question. People build far worse things than that (i.e. nuclear bombs that can kill millions). Show that you’ve made some research effort.

Answer (score 0):

That’s haram. Someone is paying you for a specific job. You have to do the job you accepted. Or decline.

To accept the job offer only to ruin the website, is unislamic, against the Sunnah and flat out haram.

The Prophet PBUH was entrusted the Meccans disbelievers money and remained true and honest. He didn’t go stealing or distributing their trust because they rejected his message and went on about their forbidden ways.